# How can I exit an external file through an exit option in python?

Tags: python

So far I have got this:

```
file=open(" The portal","w")
file.write(input("text to be written in the  file: "))
file.close()
```

However I am required to have an exit option (on python), to close the file. I've tried `exit()`, but that closes python not the file. Any ideas?

Comment: `file.close()` closes the file.. What is the problem ?

Comment: try a context manager.